# Need help to run a Github android project on an emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

New to android dev.

I want to contribute to an [open-source app that I use on a day to day basis](https://github.com/rignaneseleo/SlimSocial-for-Facebook) but I'm struggling to run it on an emulator on Android Studio.

I've cloned it on my machine, clicked 'import project (Gradle, Eclipse,.. ADT)', selected my folder..etc..

I've created a virtual device and when I click on the triangle button, the project doesn't appear as an app on the phone?

There are some build errors which I suspect are the source of my problems but I have no idea how to resolve them.

```
Error:(11, 33) java: package android.support.v4.widget does not exist   
Error:(28, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SwipeRefreshLayout
  location: class it.rignanese.leo.slimfacebook.MessagesActivity
```

_

```
Error:(18, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(19, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(96, 44) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ContextCompat
  location: class it.rignanese.leo.slimfacebook.PictureActivity
Error:(102, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class it.rignanese.leo.slimfacebook.PictureActivity
```

_

```
Error:(17, 33) java: package android.support.v4.widget does not exist
Error:(46, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SwipeRefreshLayout
  location: class it.rignanese.leo.slimfacebook.MainActivity
```

Googling on stackoverflow suggested adding a line to the dependencies section in build.gradle, but it already contains `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` so the errors shouldn't be there, right?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: android.support.v4.widget I this it happens if you dont have that library. You should migrate your project to androidX or you should download that library.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll take a look.